# Include a hyperlink as part of a sentence in a powepoint slide with Officer?

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

I am trying to use the excellent Officer package to produce a set of slides with some automated analyses. In the last slide I would like to include a list of sites and links.

For example "RStudio: https://rstudio.com/"

Is there a way of doing this with officer? I see that it is possible to use ph_hyperlink but cannot figure out how to concatenate with unlinked text. An alternative could be flextable but not ideal.

Appreciate any help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using ph_add_text and the href option.